# Retain select columns and filter the rest based on string

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, grepl

I have a dataset where I want to filter out by a specific string but retain two columns in addition to those filtered.

For example.

```
help <- data.frame(
data  = c(type, 100, 100, 110, 110, 110),
user1 = c("red", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
user2 = c("blue", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
user3 = c("red", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
user4 = c("blue", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
more_data = c(5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3))
```

I'm hoping to filter out the users with the color "red" in the first row of their data but also retain `data` and `more_data`.

For example, my end dataset would look like this:

```
  data user1 user3 more_data
1  type  red  red   5
2  100   yes  yes   3
3  100    no  no    6
4  110   yes  yes   3
5  110    no  no    4
6  110   yes  yes   3
```

Is this some sort of filter + grepl command where I filter the reverse of blue? `filter(help, grepl(!"blue", help))` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select` with `where` to check for `any` 'red' value or in the `first` element

```
library(dplyr)
help %>% 
   select(data, where(~ 'red' %in% first(.)), more_data)
```

-output

```
#  data user1 user3 more_data
#1 type   red   red         5
#2  100   yes   yes         3
#3  100    no    no         6
#4  110   yes   yes         3
#5  110    no    no         4
#6  110   yes   yes         3
```

#### data

```
help <- structure(list(data = c("type", "100", "100", "110", "110", "110"
), user1 = c("red", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"), user2 = c("blue", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"), user3 = c("red", "yes", "no", 
"yes", "no", "yes"), user4 = c("blue", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", 
"yes"), more_data = c(5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, akrun. Two follow up questions. Can you explain the tilde within the where command and the (.) within first? How do both of those function? Is the (.) just saying first row?

Comment: @b222 it is lambda function i.e. anonymous fucntion created on the fly `~` is shorthand concise option in tidyverse for `function(x)` and by default it is `.` or `.x` in tidyverse.  By calling `first(.)`, it is extracting the first element of columns, then we check whether it is equal to 'red' with red %in%

Comment: @b222 you may also pass it as `help %>% 
   select(data, where(function(x) 'red' %in% first(x)), more_data)` or create a function i.e. `f1 <- function(x) 'red' %in% first(x); help %>% select(data, where(f1), more_data)`

Comment: That helps clear things up even further. Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity... if there were other character strings in that first row... for example some said "color, red" and others said "red" and I still wanted to search each column's first row for the string "red" (regardless of any other text), how would I include that in the above function?

Comment: Is that where I'd use grepl to search the entire cell for "red" and include if found...

Comment: @b222 in that case you can `grepl('red', first(.))` or `stringr::str_detect(first(.), 'red')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229412/discussion-between-b222-and-akrun).

Comment: @b222 I am in the chat

Comment: I'm running into a problem where I know need to search all rows of some specific columns, not just `first(.)` and I can't figure out how to search all rows (and purr cheatsheet isn't helping. Any ideas?

Comment: @b222 Can you post as a new question with some example so that it becomes easier

Comment: Definitely. Was thinking the same thing. I'll post that shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @b222 Have you tried removing the `first` i.e `help %>% 
   select(data, where(~ 'red' %in% .), more_data)` As the lhs of '%in%' is of length 1 i.e. 'red', it returns a logical vector of length 1.  It should have worked

Comment: This helps but will need to run my issue to ground prior to responding... It is a big dataset so want to make sure I ask one question and not a series of them :)

Comment: @b222 ok, sure.  If you are finding any issue, when you post as question please make sure to include all the issues in that example and a reproducibe example because it may work in your example and not in your original data